# Error - Android failed linking resource on androidx CardView widget

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-xml, androidx, android-cardview

All the XML files are ok, I have checked and they have no errors, this error started soon after I copied my card-view code to various xml files, the card-view code was once working perfectly in one file, before
I generated other layouts from it

[image]

On all these XML files the needed resources are grayed out, see below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check whether the cardview tag is closed properly
2. if yes, can you add full .xml file

Comment: Yes its closed properly, the thing is, I have nested card-view elements, it does look ok on the design palette. But I don't know where the error is coming from. I have tried removing the outer card view in this file but still the same error pops on all the other xml files on card-view tags

Comment: ..... by the way I cant add the file on this platform, coz its abt 20000 characters bigger than the allowed max

Comment: Notice the above error is appearing on all XML files where androidx card view is being used, except the original file I used to generate the card view code for other layouts.